# I want to extract the last number in string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

in my dataframe have

[image]

I want output like this

[image]

i'm use

```
df2["LOSS_CIRCULATION"] = df2["LOSS_CIRCULATION"].str.extract(r"([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)")
```

but output be

[image]

Comment: Please do not include data snippets as images in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last number in the strings is `r"([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)\s*$"` (note the End-of-String marker `$` with optional spaces in front of it).

Also, use `r"([-+]?(:?\d*\.\d+|\d+))\s*$"` if you allow the last number to be negative.